# dashbot.io integration with dialogflow-fulfillment and WebhookClient

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using the "dialogflow-fulfillment" npm package and the WebhookClient class for my fulfillment app. I'm looking to integrate with dashbot.io, but the documentation doesn't detail integration with WebhookClient. There's instructions on how to integrate with DialogflowApp through "actions-on-google" but none for WebhookClient.

When I use the configHandler method like so ...

```
const dashbot = require('dashbot')('API_KEY').google;

const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
dashbot.configHandler(agent);
```

... the requests are logged to dashbot.io but not my responses.

Do I need to do something specific to integrate WebhookClient with dashbot.io or is it not fully supported?

Comment: Is there a reason why not to use `actions-on-google`?

Comment: Ideally, I want to use dialogflow-fulfillment and the WebhookClient as they provide support for multiple integrations i.e. Google Assistant, Slack, Facebook, etc.